# Data change in an interceptor is not reflecting in a component and vice versa. How can I achieve this?

Tags: angular

I have an error.interceptor.ts and app.component.ts. There is a variable called `errorMsgShown` inside the error.interceptor.ts.

I am changing the value of `errorMsgShown` at both places, interceptor and component.  But the updated value at one place is not reflecting in the other. I am suspecting that when I imported the interceptor file within the component in order to access the variable, a new instance of the interceptor is created. That's why the data is not reflecting properly - my guess.

App.component.ts has `import { ErrorInterceptor } from './core/services/http/error.interceptor';`. It is also written as a parameter in the constructor, `private errorInterceptor: ErrorInterceptor` and I am setting the variable from the interceptor in this way `this.errorInterceptor.setPermissionErrShown(false);`

error.interceptor.ts is also written in the providers in app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
],
```

Can someone please help me out on how can I have the update value reflecting at both the places?

Comment: As far as I know, there is only one instance of the interceptor. I don't know how your code looks like, but did you already verify your guess about the multiple instances? Just place a `console.log('...')` in the constructor of the interceptor to see whether multiple instances are being created.

Comment: @majusebetter Yes, the console.log is printed twice. Do you know how I can access the variables in the same instance?

Comment: Try to annotate your interceptor class with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` and check the `console.log`s again. Is it then still printed twice?  https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Yes, even after decorating the interceptor class with ```@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })```, the console.log in the constructor is being printed twice.

Comment: Hmm, very strange - I cannot reproduce this behavior in my application. However, the solution to your problem could be a static field in your interceptor, which you can manipulate with your `setPermissionErrShown()` setter. Of course, it is not the nicest solution, but since you expect your interceptor to be a singleton anyway (...)